# Vhdl-Code testbench why are there no ports declared

Tags: vhdl

Why are there no ports declared in VHDL-code testbench?

Comment: Have you written a testbench before? If you have, did you need any ports on the entity? What would you have tied those ports to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A testbench is a closed system.  All inputs to the design under test (DUT) are driven by the testbench.  All outputs from the design under test can be observed by the testbench.  Hence, the testbench has no inputs or outputs.

Comment: There may be other components in your test environment that interact with your VHDL testbench through stimuli and result files and through top level generics.  You still don't use ports but you do interact externally.

Answer (score 0):

Testbench isn't defined in the VHDL standard, leaving it to an appeal to another authority.

See for instance ***The Electronic Design Automation Handbook***, Dirk Jansen ed., 2003, page 137:

> **4.10 Test Bench**
>
> The test of proper functionality of a VHDL model ideally starts during its development. To begin with, input signals like clock and data to stimulate the circuit and to produce response at the outputs are of interest. Later in the development cycle signal behavior at the output is of primary interest.
>
> To set up a simulation environment a so called test bench, VHDL is highly suitable. The capabilities of VHDL can be used without any restrictions. From an external point of view the test bench is a closed box surrounding the object under test thus producing an autonomous system. The test bench should be a good and complete description of the environment the circuit is exposed to.
>
> The most important characteristic of a test bench is an empty port list stated in a VHDL description one level of hierarchy above. Here the description under test is instantiated as a component. The purpose of a test bench is to produce suitable input signals and to check the outputs in a way that a time consuming visual control is not necessary. There are three parts which determine the structure of a test bench:
>   • A stimuli model or the definition of test vectors at the inputs;
>   • The VHDL description under test (device under test, DUT);
>   • A response model to check or store the results of the simulation.

So it's a simulation model containing a device under test (your implementable design model), input stimulus, and potentially also provides expected results and a means of verifying them.

See *IEEE Std 1076-2008* **14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy**, Para 7:

> An implementation may allow, but is not required to allow, a design entity at the root of a design hierarchy to have generics and ports. ... ".

A VHDL implementation isn't required to elaborate and simulate a model that has top level interface lists.  You're on safe grounds if the top level of your model doesn't have any ports of generics. And if generics are ports are allowed to be present they don't do anything interesting.

A VHDL model simulation based on excitation - the occurrence of signal events.  Once there are no more signal events scheduled simulation time will advance to Time'HIGH and simulation will conclude.

A top level model with unconnected ports would simply execute initialization and quite without a testbench, barring the model containing a relaxation oscillator invoking delay - and that couldn't be synthesized.

We provide algorithmic stimulus models written in VHDL in the testbench to keep simulation active while exercising functionality for verification purposes.